# How to change default timezone dynamically for ActiveRecord in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, timezone, rails-activerecord

In my `application_controller.rb`

```
before_action :set_user_time_zone

def set_user_time_zone
  Time.zone = 'Kolkata'
end
```

I added the above code to change the Time-zone dynamically. But it does not change the Time-zone.I have time_zone field for each user in user table, I want to change time_zone according to current user. How to change Time.Zone dynamically?

Comment: I think this [blog](https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/168-dealing-with-timezones-effectively-in-rails) is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You could put a filter in your application controller that will apply to all actions in all controllers to use the user's time zone when dealing with dates and times.

This code to do that comes from [Sebastian Porto](https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/168-dealing-with-timezones-effectively-in-rails) and assumes you have a `:time_zone` column for users. It defaults to using UTC if it can't get the user time zone.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  around_filter :set_time_zone

  def set_time_zone(&block)
    time_zone = current_user.try(:time_zone) || 'UTC'
    Time.use_zone(time_zone, &block)
  end
end
```

Comment: How to check if time_zone is set to current_user(:time_zone)..? @Toby

Comment: Time.zone.name == current_user.time_zone